# Trouble with 'order by' using a subtraction between dates (one of them comes from a query)

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I don't know if this is even possible, but I want to order the results of my query by the time passed between two dates, one of them coming from a query.

What I want is to order the albums from DISCS so that the ones that have a REL_DATE closer to other date (given by the second query) appear first. The "SELECT ORDER_S..." query returns a single date extracted from another table and works fine by itself.

```
SELECT ALBUM
FROM DISCS
ORDER BY
  ABS((
  SELECT ORDER_S
  FROM SALE_LINE
  WHERE E_MAIL = (
    SELECT E_MAIL FROM CLIENTS
    WHERE DNI = 46470063
  ) AND ROWNUM = 1
  ORDER BY ORDER_S DESC)
  - REL_DATE) ASC;
```

Where ALBUM is a string type attribute, and ORDER_S and REL_DATE are DATE type attributes.

However, all I get is an error on the `ORDER BY ORDER_S DESC)` line, "missing right parenthesis", and I can't figure out why.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  You should also describe what you want the query to be doing.  Also qualify the column names so it is apparent what tables they are coming fromm.

Comment: Thank you for the advice @GordonLinoff, I've tried to add more detail in order to better explain the situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct syntax would be:

```
SELECT d.ALBUM
FROM DISCS d
ORDER BY
  ABS((SELECT MIN(sl.ORDER_S)
       FROM SALE_LINE sl
       WHERE sl.E_MAIL = (SELECT c.E_MAIL
                          FROM CLIENTS c
                          WHERE c.DNI = 46470063
                         ) 
      ) - d.REL_DATE
     ) ASC;
```

I cannot say if this does anything useful.

Comment: Thank you, this solved the problem. I suppose it was because of the `ROWNUM` having a strange behaviour when integrated inside another query.

Comment: The `rownum` is evaluated *before* the `order by`, so your code did not do what you expected.